# Java interface to only define method names (ie variable argument)

Tags: java

Let's say I want to create some CRUD resources. Each will have `create`, `update`, `delete`, `fetch`, and `list` method. The return type for all of these would be identical, but the argument to these things will be different.

Is there a way that I can create an interface that defines the return type and the method name, but allows for variable argument?

For example,

```
class User implements CRUD {
    int create(final String first_name, final String last_name);
}

class Country implements CRUD {
    int create(final String name);
}
```

Both have a `create` method that returns `int`, but each has a different argument.

Comment: Is there a way to define multiple methods with the same name and different return types? **No**.

Comment: As you seem to have discovered, it would be near impossible to create a "generalised" interface which could possible cover all the possible combinations you might ever need.  You could uses a "generic" approach, where the properties for the operation come from a different, "generic" source, but that runs the risk of it not having available information (you'd run into the same issue using a `Map`).  You could change tact and define the `CRUD` so that it passes in some kind of "configuration" object to which the implementation must provide information to...as an idea

Comment: You could turn the concept on it's head and define one or interfaces which describe the operations, ie `insertable`, `deletable`, `updatable`, to which your objects would then implement these.  Each `interface` would describe a zero parameter method, such as `insert()`, which the object would need to implement, in it' own unique way and you could then pass onto your "persistence" layer, which would just call the appropriate method...

Comment: My "personal" desire would be getting to a point where you could just go `instanceOfUser.insert()`, but this would likely require some kind of factory which could generate the implementations.  Another choice would be to pass the "persistence API" into the method, for example - `instanceOfUser.insert(persistenceEngine)` which could then configured in some abstract way to store the properties of the object

Comment: but what is a point of this interface then? as you can't really use it anymore as normal interface as it would be impossible to call "create" method on some generic "crud" instance as you don't know that parameter types. Maybe you want something jak spring repositories? interfaces with methods that are scanned via reflections to implement them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flavour of @Bohemian's solution would be to have a generic interface and objects encapsulating the methods parameters

```
class UserParam {
    String fristName;
    String lastName;
}

class CountryParam {
    String name;
}

interface CRUD<T> {
    int create(T param);
}

class User implements CRUD<UserParam> {
    int create(UserParam param) {
        // do something based on received param of type UserParam
    }
}

class Country implements CRUD<CountryParam> {
    int create(CountryParam param) {
        // do something based on received param of type CountryParam
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Type the interface:

```
interface CRUD<T> {
    int create(T arg);
}
```

where T may be `List<String>` or `String[]` or a value object.

Or, to change the *number* of arguments, if they are the same type:

```
interface CRUD {
    int create(String... args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the only hacky way to do it with some limitation is to define method signature as follows

int create(String... parameters);

In that way you can only provide String parameters, all implementing classes should parse given input array in a predefined way.

In the end, it's a bad idea!